# R freezed after devtools::build_vignettes()

Tags: r, devtools

When I run `devtools::build_vignettes()` I get:

```
> devtools::build_vignettes()
Building OwenQ vignettes
Your system is ready to build packages!
```

And then R is freezed. Nothing happens, even after 15 minutes. No folder doc or inst/doc is created.

## EDIT

I also tried the following with R 3.6.1:

```
> devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

Then I get

```
Your system is ready to build packages!
√  checking for file 'C:\MyPackages\OwenQ/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'OwenQ': (8.4s)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  installing the package to build vignettes (543ms)
   creating vignettes ...
```

And same result: nothing else happens.

## EDIT

Finally, `devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)` has correctly created the vignettes! *But* there's no folder `inst/doc` in the package source folder, the vignettes only are in the package installed folder.

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=French_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] OwenQ_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        rstudioapi_0.10   knitr_1.22        magrittr_1.5     
 [5] usethis_1.5.1     devtools_2.1.0    pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.0         
 [9] rlang_0.4.0       tools_3.5.3       pkgbuild_1.0.4    xfun_0.7         
[13] sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_1.1.0         withr_2.1.2       remotes_2.1.0    
[17] yaml_2.2.0        assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.20     rprojroot_1.3-2  
[21] crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.4.1    callr_3.3.1       fs_1.3.1         
[25] ps_1.3.0          testthat_2.2.1    glue_1.3.1        memoise_1.1.0    
[29] compiler_3.5.3    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.4   prettyunits_1.0.2
```

Comment: Shooting from the hip, perhaps you're stuck at installing LaTeX packages?